# Reversing the order or an array in Excel from last to first

Tags: excel

In a workbook containing several sheets, I am referencing data from several csv files in one sheet each, sorted in ascending order by date. The original csv files are organized that way. Is it possible to invert this range by "newest to oldest" in the target sheet, without copying the data, and without VBA? Many thanks for any pointers?

The way I am doing this now is with referencing the last valid value in a row, then the second last, third last, and so on until the first. The formula I use for the first cell is:

=INDEX([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,[A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A))

The second cell:

=OFFSET(INDEX([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,[A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A)), -1, 0, 1)

The third cell:

=OFFSET(INDEX([A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,[A17U.SI.csv]A17U.SI!A:A)), -2, 0, 1)

And so on. This takes a long time, and I stil have to know how many rows exist with valid entries. It would be good to have the -1, -2 in the offset function autoincrement according to the number of rows with valid entries.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in column **A**.  In cell **C1** *(the helper cell)* enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(A:A))*(A:A<>"")))
```

This gets us the last row in column **A** with a value.  In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,C$1+1-ROW())
```

and copy down:

[image]

If the number of items in column **A** were variable, then the formula in **B1** would be:

```
=IF(ROW()>$C$1,"",INDEX(A:A,C$1+1-ROW()))
```

and **B1** would be copied down as far as the maximum length of column **A**.